# Same algorithm implementation has different retults in Python and C++?

Tags: c++, python

This python code works properly and produces proper output:

```
def fib(x):
    v = 1
    u = 0
    for x in xrange(1,x+1):
        t = u + v
        u = v
        v = t
    return v
```

But when I write the same code in C++ it gives me a different and impossible result.

```
int fib(int x)
{
    int v = 1;
    int u = 0;
    int t;
    for (int i = 1; i != x + 1; i++)
    {
        t = u + v;
        u = v;
        v = t;
    }
    return v;
}
```

I'm still learning c++.
Thanks!

Edit: C++ outputs -1408458269. 
Python outputs 20365011074 when x = 50.

Comment: Can you give an example of where they differ?

Comment: See Danial Fisher's answer below. In c++ types have specific sizes - you're overflowing a signed 32 bit int.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For what input? Python has integers of unlimited (memory limited) size, C++'s `int` usually is a four byte integer, so you'll likely have overflow.

The largest Fibonacci number representable with a signed 32-bit integer type is `fib(46) = 1836311903`.

Comment: Thank you. I used Unsigned int rather than int and it works perfect.

Comment: C++'s `unsigned long long` can go higher, up to fib(89).  Above that you need a library.

Comment: Not very far, the last you can get with 32 bits is `fib(47)`, with 64 bits, it's `fib(93)`.

Comment: @Nekew you can also use `unsigned long long` for even bigger numbers (I think somewhere around 18446744073709551615 if your compiler makes it 8 bytes). Also, please click the checkmark beside this answer if it answered your question.

Comment: I don't need to go larger than fib(50). Thank you for your help!